# mysql query dynamic date range

Tags: mysql, date-range

I've created a website showing the prices of the fruits and vegetables of my province. These prices are updated every day (aprox. +250 rows each day).

For that reason I created a MySql table to speed up the access to this information.

On the table showed on my [Web site](http://www.pizarradeprecios.net) I want to limit the date showed up to 1 week and not all the dates available on the database. Taking in consideration that the database is increased daily I need a query for this dynamic date request.

They query I'm using right now is:

```
 SELECT base_beta.Tipo,
    base_beta.fecha_numero,
    base_beta.Variedad,
    base_beta.Fecha,
    base_beta.alhondiga,
    base_beta.corte_uno,
    base_beta.corte_dos,
    base_beta.corte_tres,
    base_beta.corte_cuatro,
    base_beta.corte_cinco,
    base_beta.corte_seis,
    base_beta.corte_siete,
    base_beta.corte_ocho,
    base_beta.corte_nueve,
    base_beta.corte_diez,
    base_beta.corte_once,
    base_beta.corte_doce,
    base_beta.corte_trece,
    base_beta.corte_catorce,
    base_beta.corte_quince
 FROM base_beta
 WHERE 1=1 
 AND base_beta.Tipo = 'pi'
 ORDER BY base_beta.fecha_numero DESC
```

There are serveral columns with corte (aka prices) because every item has a random number of prices, since the fruits and vegetables has a bid system where prices decrease on every round.

For example, a tomato may start at 0,80€ and then its prices decrease to 0.76, 0.74, 0.69 and so on.

What code do I have to add to show the data of the current day and the next 6 days to complete a week?

Here are a photo of the: [database content and format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reajM.png)

Thanks, Jose.

Comment: Edit your question and show what the date formats look like.  Also, having multiple columns with the same information, just distinguished by numbers is usually a sign of poor database design.  Typically, you would want one row per value, rather than pivoting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this defines your table schema

```
CREATE TABLE prices (item INT UNSIGNED, price DECIMAL(5,2), date DATETIME);
```

the following query will retrieve prices up to 7 days back in time

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE date > SUBDATE(CURDATE(),7) AND date <= CURDATE();
```

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Hope this helps.